# Reading Humidity Sensor Measurement via I2C

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, stm32, i2c

I have a [Honeywell humidity sensor](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/187/hih8000-datasheet-009075-7-en-1140826.pdf) which communicates with a STM32F4Discovery microcontroller. 
In this [following datasheet](https://sensing.honeywell.com/i2c-comms-humidicon-tn-009061-2-en-final-07jun12.pdf), it is written, that to start a measure cycle, first a *write bit (0)* must be sent, then, after the measurement cycle, one can fetch the *14 bit resulution* data. This is the following sequence:
[image: Sending the write bit]

[image: reading sequence]

Now, I have have the following code, written with STMCube software using HAL libraries:

```
uint8_t buf[2]; // 2 bytes
while(1){
 if (HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, 78, 5, 10) == HAL_OK){
   res = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, 78, 0, 2, 5); // start the writing cycle with bit 0;
   if (res == HAL_OK){
     HAL_Delay(40);
     res = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, 78, 1, 2, 5); // read the data (read bit 1)
       if (res == HAL_OK){
         val = ((int16_t)(buf[0] & 0x3F) << 8) | ((int16_t)buf[1] ); // combining the bytes
         humidity = ((float)val/16382.0)*100.0; 
       }
       HAL_Delay(500);
    }
  }
}
```

My question: is this code correct for reading the value? My final humidity value is a bit off, by about 10% so I wonder, if the error comes from the electrical parts and wiring scheme or am I missing something in the code?

Also, how is the **0x3F** byte calculated? What does it affect here and how to determine what value it should have?

Comment: The STM32F4 library I'm using has `HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint16_t DevAddress, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout);` declared as the function prototype. You're supposed to be passing a pointer for the 3rd parameter `pData`, while you're passing a constant value. You're never passing your `buf` array to the function, so whatever is there is 'random-ish' garbage of whatever's in the stack.

Comment: You're also misinterpreting what is meant by sending a 0 or 1 at the end of the 1st I2C write. That bit is supposed to be part of the address. So you'd use either `78` or `79` depending on whether you're sending a 0 for a write or a 1 for a read.

Comment: What you should be doing is something like `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, 78, NULL, 0, 5);` to start the measurement cycle, then (after a delay to allow the measurement to complete) `HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, 79, buf, 2, 5);` to read the result.

Comment: Master Receive does not need odd read addresses. Both transmit and receive can use same even 8-bit address. Besides it's a register based chip, so no need to build read and write yourself, the Mem_Read and Mem_Write can be used.

Comment: @Justme is correct - you don't even need to change the address from 78 to 79 because the HAL library code does that for you.

Comment: @brhans so in summary, to start the measurement cycle:
`HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, 78, NULL, 0, 5);`

then, no need to write the "read bit" command line,

and finally, this is the reading. 
`HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, 78, buf, 2, 5);`
should it be *buf or simply buf?

Comment: Yes, that should do it, and no not `*buf` because that derefences `buf` as if it were a pointer and gives you the value stored there (which you don't want to do) - you want to pass the address of `buf`, so either `&buf` or just `buf` (since in C an array decays to a pointer to its 1st element).